# Best way to make a system which is both 120 and 220 Volt compatible

Tags: transformer

I am currently preparing a piece of equipment that needs to run of both USA 120 volt and euro 220 Volt. I am running a 120 volt AC vacuum pump and a 6.3 volt transformer to provide 6.3 volts to a resistive heater. I imagine a switched 220 to 120 volt transformer before the pump and 6.3 volt transformer could achieve this.

Alternatively, I am considering running a different DC powered vacuum pump off an AC/DC power supply that will readily accept 110-240 volts input. I believe the DC power method is less cost and energy efficient and would need a cooling fan. I also would need to find a 6.3 volt power supply which is a bit hard to find.

Comment: What is the expected power consumption of the equipment? The cost of classic transformers and AC/DC converters are not very different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make sure all your components are able to run on low voltage DC power, and then, use a listed switching power supply with a wide input range.

This will also make it easier to comply with design safety standards such as CE or UL White Book.

You could have a low voltage port on your machine, which would then take an already listed brick or wall-wart power supply matched to the locality. I.E. you ship Europlug power bricks to Europe, BS1363 to UK, NEMA 1-15 to North America, etc.

Since 6.3V is difficult for you to find, I would consider an intermediate voltage such as 12V, 19V, 24V etc.

For the heater either change the spec, or use a DC/DC converter.

For the pump, I recognize the difficulty of finding *quality* low voltage pumps. Worst case, you can use a DC-AC inverter to run the AC pump.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to answer without some idea of the power involved. A two stage 1/3 HP vacuum pump is going to lead to different thinking than a small sampling pump.

If it's closer to the latter, I think I'd tend to look for a brushless DC motor vacuum pump that will run from 24VDC or 12VDC (or maybe 36VDC) and  use a simple buck converter DC-DC for the heater. Then you could use a stock serviceable power supply with a standard IEC power plug etc.